# Not able to add onCompleteListener

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

```
private void createUserAcccount(String email, String name, String password) {
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

I want to know after this is completed but when I add addOnCompleteListener it shows unable to resolve symbol. What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailpassword
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                //task completed
                if(task.isSuccessfull()) Log.d("signIn","success"); //sign in success
                else Log.d("signIn","fail") //sign in failed
            });
```

This will help you

Comment: Thank You, by this method I was able to add onCompleteListener

Comment: I know because you were not using lambda maybe so that could have been an issue. As lambda is in use nowadays, it would have showed and error